# How to embed rt.jar into my WAR using maven

Tags: maven, jar, java

How can I embed one of the JRE libraries (say, **rt.jar**) into my WAR using Maven?

Is there a maven plugin/command to do so?

Comment: i completely understand and appreciate the fact that rt.jar is JRE provided and should not be bundled. I was trying this in a different context altogether, and just want you all to accept that for now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting an `rt.jar` file into your WAR file is not going to cause Java to use it.  The web container's classloader should always try the system classloader before looking at the JARs in your webapp, and the system classloader will use the `rt.jar` on the boot classpath; i.e. the one that is in the JRE installation directory.

This is just as well.  If the Java runtime used your `rt.jar` it could get into an awful mess.  Code in your `rt.jar` could try to make calls to native methods that are not implemented in the Java executable, or it could make calls to internal methods whose behavior and/or signatures have changed in an incompatible way.

---

If you are planning to do this to "fix" some behavior in the class library, my advice would be:

1. Don't do it ... figure out a workaround instead.
2. If you have to do it, then do it by checking out the OpenJDK sources, patching the "bug", building a new JDK / JRE and using *that* as your JRE.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's a good idea. `rt.jar` is part of your JRE and is best kept separate.

Comment: +1: Thre `rt.jar` needs to be from the same version/update of JRE as the one you are using. This is because this jar will use JVM version/update specific features. Trying to ship a different version can only cause you grief.

Answer (score 2):

As [adarshr above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660213/how-to-embed-rt-jar-into-my-war-using-maven/7660257#7660257) has already pointed out, **it's not a good idea** to provide your own JRE jars.

Just in case you need to include some other jar you don't find on the maven repositories, you can add downloaded jars following these steps:

1. Put rt.jar in the maven local repository, with for instance

   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myjar.jar -DgroupId=some.group -DartifactId=someartifact Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
2. Place a dependency to this rt.jar on the pom.xml

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>`
3. When building the artifact, someartifact.jar will be included in it.

Comment: (But don't do it ... see @adarshr's answer.)

Comment: @StephenC yeah, I know, every time you include rt.jar in your projects ... <insert horrible things here>